# Ruby 1.9.3 Dir.glob strange recursive match behaviour

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

Assuming a directory structure of:

```
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
```

I am trying to find 'h' via:

```
Dir.glob('a/**/f/g/h')
```

However this is not working. Any ideas?

You can try the test case below:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ ruby -e "puts Dir.glob('a/**/*')"
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d/e
a/b/c/d/e/f
a/b/c/d/e/f/g
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ ruby -e "puts Dir.glob('a/**/h')"
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ ruby -e "puts Dir.glob('a/**/g/h')"
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ ruby -e "puts Dir.glob('a/**/f/g/h')"
**nothing**
```

Comment: The more I dig into this, the more I think it may be a bug worth reporting upstream. It seems the match fails whenever there's more than two trailing path elements. My answer below addresses the current behavior, but it probably *is* a bug in Dir#glob, since File#fnmatch works correctly.

Comment: I think it's a bug too.  On REE 1.8.7, the last command has output as expected.

Comment: Bug report link: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6977

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug and has been solved with changeset r36905. Yay!

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6977